# How to improve performance of this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I am solving a puzzle (Finding if there exists an input for a given automata for which no matter what the starting state is, final state would be same everytime) and have written following python code. A few testcases are written in check method in the code. For these cases program is running fairly fast. However, for testcases where 50 lists(nodes) are present, the programis taking forever to execute. I am storing intermediate results to use further as well. Can someone please review the code and give suggestions on how to increase the performance of the code?

```
from itertools import product
from copy import deepcopy

class Node:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.dict = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(id) + " : " + str(self.dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(id) + " : " + str(self.dict)

def tryDelete(nodes,_len):
    for id in nodes:
        y = deepcopy(nodes)
        x = y[id]
        del y[id]
        for id,node in y.items():
            for input,result in node.dict.items():
                if result == x:
                    if x.dict[input] == x:
                        node.dict[input] = node
                    else:
                        node.dict[input] = x.dict[input]
                    pass
        if pathPossible(y,_len ,False) == -1:
            return x.id
    return -2

target = {}
def FindTarget(node,p):
    if len(p) == 1:
        return node.dict[p[0]]
    if node not in target or p not in target[node]:
        x = FindTarget(node,p[:-1]).dict[p[-1]]
        if node not in target:
            target[node] = {}
        target[node][p] = x
    return target[node][p]

def allSatisy(nodes,p):
    x = None
    for key,node in nodes.items():
        if x is None:
            x = FindTarget(node,p)
        elif FindTarget(node,p) != x:
            return False
    return True

def allPossiblePaths(l,n):
    #x = int(((l+1)*(l+2))/2)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for p in product(range(l),repeat=i):
            yield p

def pathPossible(nodes,_len ,isItereate=True):
    i = 1
    isFound = False
    for p in allPossiblePaths(_len,len(nodes)):
        if allSatisy(nodes,p):
            isFound = True
            break

    if isFound:
        return -1
    elif not isItereate:
        return -2
    else:
        return tryDelete(nodes,_len)

def answer(li):
    nodes = {}
    for i in range(len(li)):
        nodes[i] = Node(i)
    for i in range(len(li)):
        for j in range(len(li[i])):
            nodes[i].dict[j] = nodes[li[i][j]]
    return pathPossible(nodes,len(nodes[0].dict))

def check(li,ans):
    # each item in the list is a node, each item i-th in the inner list tells to what node the transition happens for input i
    x = answer(li)
    print(str(li) + " : " + str(ans) + " : " + str(x))

def main():
    check([[2,1],[2,0],[3,1],[1,0]],-1)
    check([[1,2],[1,1],[2,2]],1)
    check([[1,3,0],[1,0,2],[1,1,2],[3,3,3]],-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPDATE:** I have done few code changes, but still this needs some review from you guys. Changed code:

```
from itertools import product
from copy import deepcopy

class Node:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.dict = {}

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " : " + str(self.dict)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " : " + str(self.dict)

def tryDelete(nodes,_len):
    for i in range(len(nodes)):
        y = nodes[:]
        x = y[i]
        del y[i]
        tNodes = []
        for node in y:
            for input,result in node.dict.items():
                if result == x:
                    node.tDict = deepcopy(node.dict)
                    if x.dict[input] == x.id:
                        node.dict[input] = node
                    else:
                        node.dict[input] = x.dict[input]

        if pathPossible(y,_len ,False) == -1:
            return x.id
        for n in tNodes:
            n.dict = n.tDict
            del n.tDict
    return -2

target = {}
def FindTarget(node,p):
    if len(p) == 1:
        return node.dict[p[0]]
    if node not in target or p not in target[node]:
        x = Gnodes[FindTarget(node,p[:-1])].dict[p[-1]]
        if node not in target:
            target[node] = {}
        target[node][p] = x
    return target[node][p]

def allSatisy(nodes,p):
    x = None
    for node in nodes:
        if x is None:
            x = FindTarget(node,p)
        elif FindTarget(node,p) != x:
            return False
    return True

def allPossiblePaths(l,n):
    #x = int(((l+1)*(l+2))/2)
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for p in product(range(l),repeat=i):
            yield p

def pathPossible(nodes,_len ,isItereate=True):
    i = 1
    isFound = False
    for p in allPossiblePaths(_len,len(nodes)):
        if allSatisy(nodes,p):
            isFound = True
            break

    if isFound:
        return -1
    elif not isItereate:
        return -2
    else:
        return tryDelete(nodes,_len)

Gnodes = []
def answer(li):  
    Gnodes[:] = []
    for i in range(len(li)):
        Gnodes.append(Node(i))#[i] = Node(i)
    for i in range(len(li)):
        for j in range(len(li[i])):
            Gnodes[i].dict[j] = li[i][j]
    return pathPossible(Gnodes,len(Gnodes[0].dict))

def check(li,ans):
    x = answer(li)
    print(str(li) + " : " + str(ans) + " : " + str(x))

def main():
    check([[2,1],[2,0],[3,1],[1,0]],-1)
    check([[1,2],[1,1],[2,2]],1)
    check([[1,3,0],[1,0,2],[1,1,2],[3,3,3]],-1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This may be acceptable for Code Review as long as **(A)** the code works **(B)** the code is not hypothetical or unfinished

Comment: Hi, the code works for the given test cases in `main` method and the code is finished too. I just need few pointers on how to improve the code

Comment: did you profile your code to see where the code get stuck?Once you have done that, please come back to us.

Comment: Btw. if it is about speed, Python specifically Python 3.x could be the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wonderful graph library called NetworkX.  It deals with creating graphs and path finding.  You specify what edges or paths exist in your Graph and you can find paths using a plethora of algorithms like breadth first search, or A*, and many others in the [algorithms section](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.html).  The best way to optimize your time is code reuse.
https://networkx.github.io